# How to combine two linq queries using Union

Tags: c#, linq

I have two Linq queries to `Merge` both I want to use `Union`, How can I do that

Query 1

```
var result = (from pni in _entities.PushNotificationInfoes
      join ssg in _entities.StudentStaffGuardians on pni.UniqueID equals ssg.StaffId
      join st in _entities.Students on ssg.StudentId.GetValueOrDefault() equals  st.StudentID
      where st.OrganizationID == orgId
      select new
      {
          pni.UserID,
          pni.PNToken,
          pni.OSType,

      }).ToList()
```

Query 2

```
var result = (from pni in _entities.PushNotificationInfoes
    join ssg in _entities.StudentGuardians on pni.UniqueID equals ssg.StaffId
    join st in _entities.Students on ssg.StudentId.GetValueOrDefault() equals st.StudentID
    where st.OrganizationID == orgId
    select new
    {
        pni.UserID,
        pni.PNToken,
        pni.OSType,

    }).ToList()
```

Directly how to do, from query one like `}).ToList().Union`?

Comment: What's the difference between two?

Comment: difference is there ssg table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should look like this:

```
var result = (from pni in _entities.PushNotificationInfoes
  join ssg in _entities.StudentStaffGuardians on pni.UniqueID equals ssg.StaffId
  join st in _entities.Students on ssg.StudentId.GetValueOrDefault() equals  st.StudentID
  where st.OrganizationID == orgId
  select new
  {
      pni.UserID,
      pni.PNToken,
      pni.OSType,

  })
  .Union(
    from pni in _entities.PushNotificationInfoes
    join ssg in _entities.StudentGuardians on pni.UniqueID equals ssg.StaffId
    join st in _entities.Students on ssg.StudentId.GetValueOrDefault() equals st.StudentID
    where st.OrganizationID == orgId
    select new
    {
        pni.UserID,
        pni.PNToken,
        pni.OSType,

    }).ToList();
```

As per your comment I guess you don't understand how the query is executed. All query text before `.ToList()` is just query composition. When you feel you are done with the query and are ready to execute it, you should invoke `.ToList()`

Comment: You are not writing `.ToList` before `.Union`?

Comment: no need to write `.ToList` before `.Union`

Comment: last should be this `})).ToList();` or this  `}).ToList());`

Comment: Should be the same as in my answer. `})).ToList();`

Comment: FYI: We can write `.Union(`  as well instead if `.Union((`.

Comment: Yeah, we can. Sometimes I secure myself with parentheses. I will edit the answer. Tanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result1 = (from pni in _entities.PushNotificationInfoes
      join ssg in _entities.StudentStaffGuardians on pni.UniqueID equals ssg.StaffId
      join st in _entities.Students on ssg.StudentId.GetValueOrDefault() equals  st.StudentID
      where st.OrganizationID == orgId
      select new
      {
          pni.UserID,
          pni.PNToken,
          pni.OSType,
      });

var result2 = (from pni in _entities.PushNotificationInfoes
    join ssg in _entities.StudentGuardians on pni.UniqueID equals ssg.StaffId
    join st in _entities.Students on ssg.StudentId.GetValueOrDefault() equals st.StudentID
    where st.OrganizationID == orgId
    select new
    {
        pni.UserID,
        pni.PNToken,
        pni.OSType,
    });

var result = result1.Union(result2).ToList();
```

There is no need to use `ToList` on `result1` and `result2`. By doing it this way the union can resolve in the persistence layer (if this is EF).

Comment: Can u please tell me how to do like this `}).ToList().Union`? as I mentioned in question.Thank u.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 - Just add `ToList` back at the end like you had it before I removed it from `result1` and `result2`.